# increasing names in C# with integers

Tags: c#

I need to get an object and check if it already exists.

In case it does, I want to add a number, or increase the number in its name.
For example if I have the object "a" and it exists, I need to add a 1 so it's called a1.
In case a1 exists, a2, etc.

How could I perform this?

My code:

```
if (e.TreeNode.Tag is Variant)
{
    if (variantExists(e.TreeNode.Text))
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int randomNumber = r.Next(0, 99);
        e.TreeNode.Text = e.TreeNode.Text + randomNumber;
        //e.TreeNode.Remove(); 
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code would be very helpfull...

Comment: Do you have code examples of anything you have attempted so far?

Comment: Whats the motivation...?

Comment: define `object`. It could be an array, different files, etc.

Comment: In order for us to answer, you should detail (and preferably as @GuillaumeSlashy and Kev said, add some code) how do you persist and read names.

Comment: Well basically, I have a trash can where objects can be after they've been deleted, but if an object with the same name as one in the trash bin is created, then it's automatically discarded a new one has to be created. This shouldn't be like this, as the client wants to have that new object added, but with a name variation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the TreeNode class? I would add properties for Label (Name without Index) and Index and make the Name property read only, i.e

```
class TreeNode
{
    public int Index {get;set;}
    public string Label {get;set;}

    public string Name 
    {
        get { return Index == 0 ? Label : Label + Index; }
    }
}
```

In your code you just need to set the Index property to the value you need and dont worry about the whole string parsing stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
string name = "SomeName";

string tempName = name;
int n = 0;

while (DoesNameExist(tempName))
{
    n++;
    tempName = name + n;
}

name = tempName;
```

This gets ineffecient for large numbers of the same object, but that shouldn't happen right?

The problem with doing it the other way around, and stripping off trailing numbers to find the "original" name is that the original name may genuinely have numbers on it.

Eg. You say you add:

```
SomeName
SomeName99
SomeName
SomeName99
```

The above code will give you

```
SomeName
SomeName1
SomeName99
SomeName991
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this could work:

```
var existingItems = new HashSet<string>();
var items = new List<string>{"a", "b", "a"};
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var tempItem = item;
    var i = 1;
    while (!existingItems.Add(tempItem))
        tempItem = tempItem + i++;
}
```